# C# Как правильно понимать правую ассоциативность тернарного оператора?

Tags: c#, тернарный-оператор

Согласно документации ?: (тернарный оператор) правоассоциативный,
т.е выполняется так a ? b : (c ? d : e)

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Почему этот код показывает работу тернарного оператора как левоассоциативного?
Т.е. обращение к свойству Cnt должно было произойти ровно 2 раза(при x == 3), а в итоге получаем только одно обращение.

```
    static class Counter
    {
        public static int cnt;

        public static int Cnt
        {
            get
            {
                cnt++;
                return cnt;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int someValue = 128;

        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var tmp = (x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : (x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : someValue;
        // Выполнение справа-налево
        Console.WriteLine(tmp + "   cnt = " + Counter.cnt);
        // Обратите внимание, что здесь обращение напрямую к полю класса
    }
```

Comment: А я тоже за овет 1, тернарный оператор - условный, но вы не в условие, а в ветку ответа ставите `Cnt` при этом поставили условие или [1] или [2], соответственно вызов один раз происходит.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что происходит вычисление только одного из операндов - того, который возвращается в зависимости от условия.

Выделен жирным для `x == 3`:

(x == 3) ? **Counter.Cnt** : ((x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : someValue);

Выделен жирным для `x != 3`:

(x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : ((x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : **someValue**);

Comment: (x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : ((x == 3) ? Counter.Cnt : someValue); Сначала ведь тернарный оператор в скобках, а потом внешний, правоассоциативность, верно?

Comment: @wolframrus из вашей же ссылки `Если параметр condition имеет значение true, вычисляется выражение first_expression и итог этого вычисления становится результатом. Если параметр condition имеет значение false, вычисляется выражение second_expression и итог этого вычисления становится результатом.`

Comment: @wolframrus а теперь определите, что в вашем выражении вообще будет вычисляться, а что не будет